# How to move specific ellipse to a the pointer pressed position?

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm making a game in which there are different ellipses and at a time i've to select only one ellipse and move it to the position where I press the pointer. So how can I do that? (Syntax Please!).

Answer (score 0):

There are to main input events you can use - `PointerMoved` and `ManipulationDelta`. Just handle one of these events and move the ellipse based on information you get. The `sender` of the event is the `UIElement` (i.e. `Ellipse`) that was dragged.

If it's `ManipulationDelta` - you also need to specify `ManipulationMode` - e.g. `ManipulationMode="TranslateX,TranslateY,TranslateIntertia"`, but then you can just move the `Ellipse` by `eventArgs.Delta.Translation.X/Y` on each event.

With `PointerMoved` - you'll also need to check which pointer moved, whether it's pressed, track whether `PointerPressed` on that pointer was last raised on your `Ellipse` etc. I wouldn't go there.

You can move a `UIElement` using a few methods.

If it's in a `Grid` - you can move it by dx, dy by setting

```
ellipse.Margin = new Thickness(
    ellipse.Margin.Left + dx,
    ellipse.Margin.Top + dy,
    ellipse.Margin.Right - dx,
    ellipse.Margin.Bottom - dy);
```

If it's in a `Canvas` - you can move it like this:

```
var x = Canvas.GetLeft(ellipse);
var y = Canvas.GetTop(ellipse);
Canvas.SetLeft(x + dx);
Canvas.SetTop(y + dy);
```

Otherwise - if your ellipse has a `RenderTransform` - e.g. `TranslateTransform` - you would do it like this:

```
var ellipse = (Ellipse)sender;
var tt = (TranslateTransform)ellipse.RenderTransform;
tt.X += dx;
tt.Y += dy;
```

Comment: But if I first click the ellipse and then click at a point on the screen, then how can I move that ellipse to that particular point?

Comment: You could handle the `Tapped` event and get the ellipse tapped by casting the `sender` parameter to an `Ellipse`. Then you would handle the `Tapped` event elsewhere on the screen and get the position by calling `eventArgs.GetPosition(screenElement)`. You might also need to store the state somewhere to know whether you are in the "ellipse" clicking state or "screen" clicking state since there might be other ellipses you'd click after first clicking your starting ellipse to then place it and you'd want to ignore these other events. You can also use `eventArgs.Handled = true` to skip something.

Comment: There is no GetPosition method for eventArgs.

Comment: It is [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.tappedroutedeventargs.getposition.aspx).